# Comparison of parameters for enzyme kinetics using bootstrapping and ANCOVA. Is this right?

Tags: anova, bootstrap

I'm analysing the breakdown of substrates (i) that were previously treated with a first enzyme for defined time periods (j), and then subjected to a second type of enzyme (l) that will generate the final product of the sequential enzyme reaction. I'm using the 1st order kinetic model:

p (i,j,l,t) = Sij0(e^(Kijl * t))

where Sij0 is the initial amount of the i type of substrate pretreated for j time with the first enzyme, Kijl is the 1st order kinetic constant for the l enzyme acting on the i substrate pretreated j time, t is the reacion time for the l enzyme, and p(i,k,l,t) is the final product generated by the second l enzyme at the t time. Using experimental data and non-lineal regression I calculated all the Kijl±SDikl for the multiple conbinations with good correlations (r2>0.95; p<0.05) and acceptable dispersions (<10%).

I need to determine differences among the i substrtates and the l secondary enzymes. I used an ANOVA procedure for condensed values (X, SD, n). However, most comparisons showed no differences despite clear differences in the kinetics of p(i,j,l,t) production.

I decided to use something that may be called "boostrapping" approach calculating datasets of pcalc(i,j,l,t) (363 points each) using the above equation and the Kijl constants modified by addition/subtraction of a random values within 3 times the corresponding SDijk. These calculated (modeled) datasets were compared using ANCOVA with substrate (i), pretreatment (j) and second enzyme (l) as main classifiers and t time of secondary enzyme reaction as a covariate. The results appeared to make much more sense since they showed the expected differences among short and long pretreatments as well as among different secondary (l) enzymes.

Could anyone please comment on this approach? Is it right or wrong? I there a well known or accepted procedure for these type of comparisons? By the way, I'm not a coding person.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How do you use ANCOVA when the model for p (i,j,l,t) appears to be nonlinear?